# Pressing the device back button must navigate to back or backstack in Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, back, marketplace

According to 5.2.4.1 Requirements the  Expected Result for Pressing the Back button must return the application to the previous page or return to any previous page within the back stack.
If I clear the backstack and navigate to a new page on Device Back button is this a valid for market place?

Also,
If I navigate to another page and OnNavigateTo that page I clear the backstack is this also a valid for market place submission?

Thanks and Regards,
Kanaya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're clearing the back stack at some point, then navigating to a new page when the user clicks the hardware back button, then your app will fail marketplace validation. I've had it actually happen to me, and it was a bit of a headache to go back and make the app navigate "as is" without interfering with the back stack.

When you alter the normal behavior of a phone app like that, Microsoft frowns upon it. The concept they are trying to hit is a common experience across all apps, including the operating system.

It has also been my experience (doing user testing before launch of app to the marketplace) that altering the behavior of the back button as you've described is frustrating to the user because it breaks their expectations of how the app ought to operate. The user gets accustomed to the back button doing something very specific, regardless of the app they have open. You might want to reconsider the reasons you have for architecting the app the way you have, and strongly consider if there is an alternative that users will find more pleasant and natural.

But yes, I can tell you from experience that Microsoft will fail you for that.

Comment: Thanks Paul, You got me right. Thats really annoying from Microsoft. As my App UI is common for other Os- Android,IPhone and I cannot change the flow for keeping the user experience same throughout platforms. I need to get data from network  when navigating back. In this I have to check if new data is available or not, depending on this navigate to another page. This is difficult to handle if microsoft will fail it.

Comment: We struggled with that as well. I think we nailed it though. IMHO the best philosophy is to approach each platform afresh, and make your app not have a similar experience across each platform, but make your app look like it was written *just* for that platform. You will delight more users, it will look natural to those who live with their platform day in and day out. Consistent UI across platforms really only affects users who have one of each device. I think what's more important to nail is a consistent "brand" across each, with UI that's native and beautiful on each platform.

Comment: You might want to write a separate question addressing a "how do I...?" kind of question where you give a little more detail to the specific task you're trying to accomplish on the phone when the user navigates back.

Comment: Thanks Paul, You understand my situation completely. This seems that one must not have a HomeScreen in Wp7App which creates Loop. But still it seems weird that the only way to go back to my Homescreen in my app is by navigating back untill I reach the Homescreen and not clearing the backstack and navigating to Homescreen.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. While there is a "Home Screen" of sorts in every WP7 app (simply the first page), there is no quick shortcut built into the hardware that will get you there with one click. I have a sneaky suspicion that you *may* only find that odd because you are so used to using Android. I can tell you as a dedicated WP7 user (formerly iPhone), it's always seemed natural to me, and will as well to your users. A common design paradigm that many developers adopt is including an icon on the ApplicationBar that serves as a "Home" button, allowing the user to quickly jump there.

Answer (score 0):

> If I clear the backstack and navigate to a new page on Device Back button is this a valid for market place?

Most likely not, but the question is what will happen if I press back button on that page. Requirements are a bit complicated. The question you should ask yourself is "Will my app exit with ONLY back button?"

Answer (score 0):

Check the feature in the market place test kit. You will get the correct answer. see Use of back button feature in test kit.